# Asus X750JB overheads Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: asus, temperature

```
Notebook Model : Asus X750JB
CPU : Intel Core i7 4700HQ (2.40GHz)
RAM : 8GB Memory 2TB HDD
GPU : NVIDIA GeForce GT 740M
```

In standby it keeps a temperature of 46 ► 50 degrees Celsius.
The fan never stops.

When I start applications that run on Java. 
The temperature goes up to 100 degrees Celsius.
I tried use `cpulimit` (max cpu size 400%) at 100% to *java* (`cpulimit -e java -l 100`)
also to *firefox* (`cpulimit -e firefox -l 30`)

I found a tutorial to change something about `rc.local`

I have apache2, mysql, php, wine  installed.